# Add a column to the end of csv using pandas or in general python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I wrote a piece of code which reads the columns from different csv files and writes to another csv file. I want the new column to be added at the end i.e as the last column, but my implementation makes the column to add at the bottom. Suppose `a` is already existing column, `b` is the new one added, here is what I got

```
a,
1,
2,
3,
b,
1, 
2,
3,
```

but what i need is something like this

```
a,b 
1,1
2,2
3,3
```

Here is the piece of code i am working with.

```
wwr=["wwr15","wwr30","wwr45","wwr60"]
shade=["E1-geo1"]
climate=["Madrid"]
orientations=['East','North','South','West']
colMap={'East':3,'North':2,'South':1,'West':0}

for shd in shade:
  for clim in climate:

    for orientation in orientations:
        for win in wwr:
            inp_filename=shd+"_"+clim+"_"+win+"_DC_ctrl3.csv"
            col=pd.read_csv(inp_filename,usecols=[colMap[orientation]])
            output_fname=shd+"_"+clim+".csv"

            if os.path.isfile(output_fname):
                col.columns=[shd+" "+orientation+" "+clim+" "+win]
                col.to_csv(output_fname,index='false',mode='a')


            else:
                col.columns=[shd+" "+orientation+" "+clim+" "+win]
                col.to_csv(output_fname,index='false',mode='w')
```

In the above code, each of the `inp_filename` csv file has four columns and 8760 rows, i will read each column in a particular order(based on orientation) and write that into  `output_fname`csv file.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit1:** I tried this method as well, transposed each column to row and appended all of them but I see each row has indices which are not required.

```
     col=pd.read_csv(filename,usecols=[colMap[orientation]], index_col=False)
     df_read=pd.DataFrame.transpose(col)
     outputname=shd+"_"+clim+".csv"
     df_read.to_csv(outputname,index_label=shd+" "+orientation+" "+clim+" "+win, mode='a', header='False')
```

My result appeared something like this(2 rows) for every column

```
  E1-geo1 East Madrid wwr15,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,..........
  1.3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...........
```

but what i require is something like this(only 1 row) for each column

```
  E1-geo1 East Madrid wwr15,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.........
```

more over after I write this to csv file how do I transpose all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 3 CSV files.

`a.csv` has

```
a0,a1
1,a1
2,a2
```

`b.csv` has

```
b0,b1
1,b1
2,b2
```

and `c.csv` has

```
c
9
8
```

So, [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) can give you a reader for each, and `zip` can combine them, like so:

```
for tup_a, tup_b, tup_c in zip(csv.reader(open('a.csv')), csv.reader(open('b.csv')), csv.reader(open('c.csv'))):
    print tup_a + tup_b + tup_c
['a0', 'a1', 'b0', 'b1', 'c']
['1', 'a1', '1', 'b1', '9']
['2', 'a2', '2', 'b2', '8']
```

If you want to write each tuple to a new file, just use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects) instead of the `print` above.

Comment: Actually its not just combining files but its picking a column from each file and adding it to this newfile. For ex. I collect data related to east from all files once and then next direction from all files and so on.

Comment: It's the same principle. Either use `csv.reader` and just pick the element you want by index, or use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and select the key. The general structure above will still work.

Comment: your answer worked very well thanks .. But i don't understand one thing  the other guy who also answered deleted his answer and downvoted me , even i tried his suggestion and posted as an edit.. May he didn't like his own answer :P

Comment: @raghu Don't take it too hard.